# What to do when husband is having sexual dreams

Tags: islamic-philosophy, sex, husband-wife, sexuality

I've got married two years ago. After that, every time when my husband is having a sexual dream I can realize. His thing becomes hard and breaths become heavy.

I'm a practising muslim. I'm ashamed to discuss with him about this.
I just want to know is there anything I can do when he's having these type of dreams?

Comment: Can you please elaborate its relevance to Islam?, you are asking a help for a biological issue here

Comment: what do you mean by "his thing" ? Do you mean his penis ?

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of dreams.
Fist one comes from Allah SWT. Second one comes from Shaitan and the Last is from our Nafs.

Dear sister, if your husband is dreaming erotic dreams frequently than there is high probability those dreaming are coming from there Nafs.

To prevent this you can monitor his daily activity, and try to keep him satisfied with you.
Another and most effective way is to Make Dua for him before you both go for sleep. Beshak only Allah SWT listens there servant.

Note : this is not necessary condition when his thing become hard and heavy breathing. That hardness is natural for all the man. and heaving breathing might be cause. you should talk to him about what you sees.

Answer (score 0):

I found it worth creating an account here to not let you be deceived

From my personal experience from waking up during sexual dreams due to ejaculation, the body part does NOT become hard during sexual dreams nor during ejaculation afterwards. It stays "normal" just like in any other dream.

Secondly, it's very normal for it to be hard during sleep. It depends on sleep cycles. It might be the REM sleep which is the deepest sleep causing most activities in the body. Keep in mind that it's very unpleasant to be woken up at this stage as it results is nausea.

You can look up "morning wood" which refers to when it becomes hard shorlty before waking up. This is normal hormonal activity. As I said it's normal for this to happen during sleep too, it's an indication of normal hormonal activity. It isn't related to any kind of dreams.

Just like having a period doesn't mean you're thinking something sexual, this happening during sleep due to regular hormonal activity doesn't mean he's thinking something sexual.

As you said "After that, every time" it's obvious that what you suspect is not the case. Changes in breathing patterns is even more convincing: Different sleep stages.

If I were you, I would not find this case important enough to talk about it with my husband. Most likely he won't understand what you're talking about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that when men sleep, the Testosterone increases in their body so that's not abnormal to see them in that way while sleeping. However, we must also not forget the rule of Satan in the dreams. So below are some tips he can practice:

The dream is the child of the past day. usually we dream about what we think. We must be careful of our thoughts and fantasies before going to sleep, because if we cultivate any thoughts and fantasies in our minds before going to sleep, we will see them in our dreams.  In fact, our ideas, desires and inclinations are expressed in dreams. The solution is that:

During the day, we should be careful not to allow wrong thoughts to enter our minds.
Avoid reading, listening and thinking about sex, as continuing to do so has dangerous consequences, causing trouble for us in both sleep and wakefulness and depriving us of relaxation.
Try to sleep with Wudhu (Sahih form of Wudhu: https://youtu.be/snH7kSjgLuw)and recite the Qur'an a little before going to bed.
If you can, wake up after the morning call to prayer and before sunrise.
Try to control your imagination before going to bed and do not think about arousal and sexual issues.
Always have things to think about when you are unemployed or at bedtime so that you do not have the opportunity for sexual fantasies.
When sleeping, do not sleep on your stomach. Exercise regularly and a lot in order to drain the body of excess energy.
One or two days a week, the recommended fast is useful, and if you can not afford it, reduce the amount of food consumed and increase the interval between meals, or reduce the number of meals and be satisfied with the minimum amount of food.
Avoid talking softly, jokingly and laughing with strangers.

Before going to bed, recite this Dua mentioned in the authentic book Mafatih to prevent the wet dreams.
اللهّمَ اِنّي اَعُوذُ بكَ منَ الأحتلام و مِن سُوءِ الأحلامِ و مِنْ اَنْ يَتلاعَبَ بِيَ الشيطانُ في اليقَظَةِ و اَلمنامِ

---

The above tips were general solutions which means works even for single people, but as your husband is married and he still has wet dreams, that may indicate that